# WPF - Windows don´t recognize each other

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to open a new Window called second window with this code:

```
   SecondWindow openwi = new SecondWindow();
        openwi.Open;
```

But it doesn´t work, not in the MainWindow and neither in the Second window. It says CS0426: Type or Namespace "Second Window" couldn´t be found (using-Directive or Assembly could be missing).
Has anyone a solution?

Comment: Did you define `SecondWindow` in your project?

Comment: You need to reference the namespace where the `SecondWindow` exists. On VS, press `CTRL + .`.

Comment: Also, this should be `openwi.Show()` not `openwi.Open`

Comment: @bolkay  How do I define a window?

Comment: Using the context menu on the project: Add > Window (WPF)

Comment: @KlausGütter Yes, I did that. It just doesn´t recognize the window

Comment: Impossible to help without further input. At least the definition of `SecondWindow` and the *exact error message* (e.g. unlikely that it complains about "Second Window" if your class is named SecondWindow)